# Как остановить форму в зависимости от ответа Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var requestUrl = '/check_capcha.php';
    $('body').on('submit', 'form.me', function (e) {
        var postData = $("form.me").serialize();
        console.log(postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        url: requestUrl,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Как мне `e.preventDefault();` вставить в проверку даты?
код страницы check_capcha.php:

```
if (!$APPLICATION->CaptchaCheckCode($_POST["captcha_word"], $_POST["captcha_sid"]))
{
echo 0;
} else{
echo 1;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос удалять не будете как в прошлый раз? Стоит писать ответ? И в какое условие вы хотите его вставить? Что должно произойти если с сервера пришел ответ 1 или 0?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan просто после публикации сразу увидел ошибку. Причем она не несла никакого познавательного смысла для других участников, чтобы оставить вопрос и дать самому ответ на него. Просто банально не туда вставил код.
У меня есть условие `e.preventDefault();`, но мне нужно использовать его только когда с сервера приходит ответ `0`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал не много по другому, в любом случае останавливал бы событие сабмита формы, но в случае если форма валидацию прошла, то значит сабмитим форму ещё раз, но уже без биндов на сабмит этой формы. 
Вот ваш пример не много модифицированный:

```
var requestUrl = '/check_capcha.php';
$('body').on('submit', 'form.me', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var postData = $("form.me").serialize();
    console.log(postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        url: requestUrl,
        context: this,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data == 1) {
                //Валидация прошла успешно, самбитим форму ещё раз, но уже не обрабатываем событие
                $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
            }
            else {
                //Валидацию не прошел, выполняем js дальше
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Минус только в том что если есть ещё обработчики на это событие - они уже тоже не отработают.